# MySQL select all posts + additional data in different groups

Tags: mysql, select

I'm trying to select all posts from a specific category along with some additional data from another table.
Despite my efforts none of the sql queries that I've tried have worked out so far.

Here is my code.

```
SELECT 
  a.*,
  b.*
FROM forum_posts AS a 
LEFT JOIN forum_categories AS b ON a.post_category = b.category_id
WHERE category_slug = 'news-and-anouncements'
```

Here's a screenshot to illustrate the result I'm trying to achieve.

[image: screenshot]

As you can see I'm grabbing posts from the posts table, but I also wish to get the category fields without re-selecting them in each post selection, if that makes sense.

Any ideas on how I should tweak the query?

Comment: Do a full join not a left join.

Comment: What you say *doesn't* make sense (at least not to me).  What is the problem with the output you are getting?  What is the output that you really want?

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies. My current query fetches the posts within a category and puts each post inside its own stdClass Object. I would like the data in the red fields, which are from another table, to be "outside the posts". It would be perfect if the the red fields were in their own stdClass Object. Did that clear up the confusion?

Comment: I think the stdClass object is where we're getting confused.  In the strict SQL sense I think you have all the data you need.  How are you putting the data into these objects -- php/java/other?

Comment: Well I gotta go pick up my kid...I'll delete my answer since it's not helping you get what you need and hopefully someone else can help out.  I'll try and hop on when I get back home if you're still stuck.  I think what you need to do though is do the "grouping" in your PHP code, not in SQL.   Group by's in SQL are more for counting/agregating/summing then categorizing.